# How do I update the quantity column from two other tables in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables so I can display separate tables and keep track of different things.

How do I make 'pull_qty" in CARTONS_PULLED and 'add_qty' in CARTONS_ADDED update 'qty' in CARTONS _CURRENT?

When I create a new Part Number with a quantity it inserts into CARTONS_CURRENT.

Now I need to update the 'qty" in CARTONS_CURRENT with adds and pulls from the two other tables?  the 'part_no' is the primary key and is always the reference to update.

Here are my tables:

```
DATABASE NAME: _hero 

TABLE NAME:  CARTONS_CURRENT
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
| Column       |  Type        |  Null  |  Key   |  Default          |  Extra     |
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
| orig_time    | timestamp    |  No    |        | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |            |
| type         | text         |  No    |        |                   |            |
| part_no      | varchar(20)  |  No    |  Prim  |                   |            |
| description  | varchar(75)  |  No    |        |                   |            |
| count        | varchar(2)   |  No    |        |                   |            |
| size         | varchar(30)  |  No    |        |                   |            |
| min          | int(7)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
| max          | int(7)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
| qty          | int(8)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+

TABLE NAME:  CARTONS_ADDED
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
| Column       |  Type        |  Null  |  Key   |  Default          |  Extra     |
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
| add_time     | timestamp    |  No    |  Prim  | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |            |
| type         | text         |  No    |        |                   |            |
| part_no      | varchar(20)  |  No    |  Prim  |                   |            |
| add_type     | varchar(25)  |  No    |        |                   |            |
| add_qty      | int(8)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
| add_ref      | varchar(35)  |  No    |        |                   |            |
| add_by       | text         |  No    |        |                   |            |
| add_notes    | varchar(300) |  No    |        |                   |            |
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+

TABLE NAME:  CARTONS_PULLED
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
| Column       |  Type        |  Null  |  Key   |  Default          |  Extra     |
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
| pull_time    | timestamp    |  No    |  Prim  | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |            |
| type         | text         |  No    |        |                   |            |
| part_no      | varchar(20)  |  No    |  Prim  |                   |            |
| pull_type    | varchar(25)  |  No    |        |                   |            |
| pull_qty     | int(8)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
| pull_ref     | varchar(35)  |  No    |        |                   |            |
| pull_by      | text         |  No    |        |                   |            |
| pull_notes   | varchar(300) |  No    |        |                   |            |
+--------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd write [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) for the `CARTONS_PULLED` and `CARTONS_ADDED` tables which do the appropriate updates in `CARTONS_CURRENT` table. Ie something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER Upd_Cartons_qty 
AFTER INSERT ON CARTONS_ADDED FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE CARTONS_CURRENT SET qty = qty + NEW.add_qty WHERE part_no = NEW.part_no;
END;
```

if you want to add the value of `add_qty` to the `CARTONS_CURRENT.qty` when new record is inserted into `CARTONS_ADDED`.